# How to set WIP limit in Azure DevOps Board - Sprint View

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile

In Azure DevOps Boards, we can set WIP limits for columns. Unfortunately it is only possible in the Boards view but not in the Sprint view, at least I found no possibility to do it. Did I miss something or is it really not possible. And if not, does someone why it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WIP limits are used to limit the number of work items in progress, and can help identify process bottlenecks and improve the Team's efficiency. These numbers are set per stage and act as the soft constraint that can be revisited later.

As a prerequisites, **To use WIP Prerequisites, you must have a Kanban board you want to configure**. When you add a team, you add a Kanban board for that team.

In other words, it's not available to  set WIP with Sprint View. Sorry for any inconvenience, this is by designed.

Answer (score 0):

Sprint view does not support WIP because WIP comes from Kanban. Sprint view is Agile/Scrum tool. [Work in Progress limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/wip-limits?view=azure-devops):

> An essential Kanban practice—Work in Progress limits, referred to as
> "WIP limits"—constrains the amount of work your team undertakes at
> each work stage.

Comment: To be honest I don't support that argument. As Kanban is an agile framework and Azure DevOps Boards can be of type agile, there is no reason why to say that WIP are not supported because it comes from Kanban. There is no problem combining Kanban and Scrum practices, right? Also in the Board view WIP are available.

Comment: @NoahIspas I think, developers of Azure DevOps may have a more formal view on this problem: 1) Boards (as Kanban) use WIP; 2) Backlogs and Sprints (as Scrum) use story points and hours. Your suggestion to combine Kanban and Scrum practices may be interesting. You can post it to the developers: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: Apparently someone already suggested it, but didn't find much attention :(: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/609126/sprint-task-board-wip-limit.html

Comment: Agree with @NoahIspas, not supporting this answer as a good one, because Limiting WIP is a powerful practice to improve the product development flow. While indeed Scrum has a different approach (by the book, commitment, etc...) to accomplish work, it doesn't restrict usage of WIP limits.